# Regex for first character can not be space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex for first character cannot be space in JavaScript

I use this but its not working

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Your regex works pretty fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

`\s` matches any character that is unicode whitespace.
`\S` matches any character that is not unicode white space.

*So, a regex that matches to a string whose first character is a non-space character can be any of the following:*

```
/^[^\s].*/  
/^\S.*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern will match any character at the start of a string that is not whitespace.

`^\S`

If you are trying to match the whole string if it does not begin with whitespace use this.

`^\S.*$`

**[Demo](http://regexr.com/3a2j0)**

Comment: @M42 OP's pattern does not match any non-alpha numeric characters and is also needlessly complex. https://www.debuggex.com/r/dlsjoQrphPvuV0u8

Comment: May be OP wants to match only letter or digit in first position, that is what his regex means. But who knows?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work just fine for single line string but if you want to accept `\r` (Carriage Return),`\n` (Line Feed) or `\r\n` (End Of Line) then you can use the below regex:

`[^ ](.*|\n|\r|\r\n)*`

`[^ ]` : First character should not be a space.

`(.*|\n|\r|\r\n)*$` : Any character including Carriage Return, Line Feed and End Of Line, any number of times.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqDKDa/1)

Comment: It not worked for me but with your solution I have tried "^[^ ](.*|\n|\r|\r\n)*$" and it worked for me. Just inject the symbol ^ at the start and in the last $.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried "^^ *$" and it worked for me.